# executing stored procedure from Spring-Hibernate using Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, stored-procedures, oracle9i

I'm trying to execute a simple stored procedure with Spring/Hibernate using Annotations.
Here are my code snippets:

DAO class:

```
    public class UserDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport {

        public  List selectUsers(final String eid){
            return (List) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
                  public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws 
                   HibernateException, SQLException
                  {
                      Query q = session.getNamedQuery("SP_APPL_USER");
                      System.out.println(q);
                      q.setString("eid", eid);
                      return q.list();
                  }
              });
          }
    }
```

my entity class:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "APPL_USER")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @DiscriminatorFormula(value = "SUBSCRIBER_IND")
    @DiscriminatorValue("N")
    @NamedQuery(name = "req.all", query = "select n from Requestor n")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(name = "SP_APPL_USER", 
query = "call SP_APPL_USER(?, :eid)", callable = true, readOnly = true, resultClass = Requestor.class)

    public class Requestor {

    @Id
        @Column(name = "EMPL_ID")
        public String getEmpid() {
            return empid;
        }

        public void setEmpid(String empid) {
            this.empid = empid;
        }

        @Column(name = "EMPL_FRST_NM")
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
    ...
    }

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "applicationContext.xml");
            APFUser user = (APFUser)ctx.getBean("apfUser");

            List selectUsers = user.getUserDAO().selectUsers("EMP456");
            System.out.println(selectUsers);
        }

    }
```

and the stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_APPL_USER (p_cursor out sys_refcursor, eid in varchar2)
as
  empId varchar2(8);  
  fname varchar2(50); 
  lname varchar2(50); 
begin
  empId := null;  
  fname := null;  
  lname := null;  
  open p_cursor for
    select l.EMPL_ID, l.EMPL_FRST_NM, l.EMPL_LST_NM
      into empId, fname, lname
      from APPL_USER l
     where l.EMPL_ID = eid;
end;
```

If i enter invalid EID, its returning empty list which is OK.

But when record is there, following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; bad SQL grammar [call SP_APPL_USER(?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

Do I need to modify the entity(Requestor.class) ?
How will the REFCURSOR be converted to the List?
The stored procedure is expected to return more than one record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the [bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4169?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) in the hibernate.
I've modified the stored procedure to fetch ***all*** the columns and it worked well.